# Magento master-slave replication error on update

Tags: magento-enterprise, data-replication

I have setted up a MySql master-slave replication in magento enterprise 1.14.2.4. The master-slave replication works fine e.g if I create a new database in Master db, same database automatically gets created into the Slave db.
The issue I am facing is that whenever I save any system configuration I am getting a slave replication error and the values doesn't get saved.

The replication error clearly tells me that you are using a READ database connection in order to perform a WRITE (update or insert) query in the slave database. Below is my local.xml's database connection settings for this magento db replication setup.

```
<default_setup>
            <connection>
                <use />
                <host><![CDATA[server-1]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[dev]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[5YCSDQGU56DEW5GRNrOfMA]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dev.test]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
        <default_read>
            <connection>
                <use />
                <host><![CDATA[/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[dev]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[5YCSDQGU56DEW5GRNrOfMA]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dev.test]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_read>
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!